# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Gateway PC Intel i3

Tags: installation, 12.10

I have a Gateway PC with Intel Core i3. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 - 12.10 and unable to install any of them. Some messages mention that only the 64-bit version of 12.10 release works with UEFI. However the only 64-bit version that can be downloaded from Ubuntu website is based on AMD platform. Bummer!

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

The 64bit version is not AMD based.  It says AMD64 because it a naming conviction.  And Because AMD did the first commercially available 64bit chips.  You can download and install of Intel and AMD systems.

The AMD64 or x86-64 is a 64-bit processor architecture invented by AMD. It is a superset of the x86 architecture, which it natively supports. The AMD64 Instruction set is currently used in AMD's Athlon 64, Athlon 64 FX, and Opteron processors.

Intel has also implemented the AMD64 architecture in its newer Xeon and Pentium 4 F processor lines, rebranding it EM64T.<sup>[AMD](http://www.amd.com/us-en/Processors/DevelopWithAMD/0,,30_2252_875_7044,00.html)</sup>

Download Ubuntu [12.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/), and [12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) both are available the 32bit, and 64bit

Comment: I downloaded 64b version for 12.10 and 12.04. The Windows OS doesn't recognize any of them and I can't boot from the DVD either. when I use the 32-bit version windows can at least recognize the install image as Ubuntu and execute the install after which it runs into other isues.

Comment: It seems that there might be a problem either with the ISO.  Try doing an [MD5SUM](MD5SUM) on the ISO.  I have 12.04 64bit, and it boots from DVD with no problems.  Also try creating a [bootable USB](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).